# angularjs instant update upon function call

Tags: javascript, angularjs

HTML

```
{{myVar}}
```

JS

```
$scope.myVar = 0; 
function update(){
     $scope.myVar++ 
}
```

I bind the `update()` to ngclick but the `{{myVar}}` is not updating. If I put the function to self-execute,then it updates. I thought it could work like `ng-model`? what might be the issue?

Comment: please show us how you bind the function to `ng-click` in your html.

Comment: I think he mean for ajax, because I experienced the same thing. I put the function to be executed in the success scope of $http. didn't see instant update.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your function to use $scope.

**Example:**

```
$scope.myVar = 0; 
$scope.update=function(){
     $scope.myVar++ 
}
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/choroshin/5YDJW/8/

Answer (score 0):

Try `$scope.update = function(){ $scope.myVar++ }`

From what I can see, function update() is not available in the scope so angular has no way to bind to ng-click. Making it 'self-execute' or calling it immediately updates the $scope.myVar variable directly so that's why that works. This is not like using ng-model.